# How to use state value inside source of image in react native?

Tags: react-native, require

Want to define image location on constructor and want to use multiple place so my question is how to define state with url and use that state.
I have tried below code

```
this.state = {
      value: '../Assets/images/pic.png',
}

<Image source{require(this.state.value)}/>
```

but getting errors

> require expect exactly 1 string literal argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
render() {
    let value = require("../Assets/images/pic.png");
...
    <Image source={value} />
....}
```

Comment: then you can display image like this <Image source={value} />